# Quantum Crypto infrastructure & hardware

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics

To implement real quantum cryptography in the real world, does the physical link layer from Point A to Point B be an optical link for all parts? Is there any links or whitepaper containing prototypes of technical implementations over varying lengths and distances and types of networks?

Can QC be implemented over a WAN such as the global Internet, without modifications to existing physical infrastructure?

Comment: One link has to be a quantum system and your physical choices are limited... photons, neutrinos, electrons (positrons), protons, neutrons, atoms and ions and potentially quasiparticles in solid state systems. Realistically only photons are technologically useful.

Comment: There are commercially available applications performing quantum key distribution over medium ranges (<400km). Have a look at the papers of Nicolas Gisin and the firm he (co)founded: http://www.idquantique.com/resource-centre/quantum-key-distribution/ (this should give you additional information to Norbert Schuch's answer). They use photons as CuriousOne predicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement quantum cryptography, you need a link which allows to send *quantum* states, i.e., some kind of object/particle which carries a quantum degree of freedom. These particles should travel as freely as possible along their way. This is most easily accomplished using a single photon, thus the optical link, but in principle, sending e.g. individual electrons would also work, if you find a way to shield them from interactions.

ON the other hand, the internet would not work, as it only allows to send classical information.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the entire link cannot be quantum because there are parts of the network that run on copper, radio waves or non-shielded links like from device to device and will have to rely on classical encryption or other security measures?

Comment: Yes. On top of that, you cannot just cut out a part of a quantum link and replace it with a classical one, even if you wouldn't care about security, since quantum information cannot be cloned (and if it could be made classical, it could be).

Answer (score 0):

Any quantum channel will work, even if it involves temporarily holding the qubits or routing them through some convoluted path. As long as the qubits stay coherent through the trip (i.e. aren't measured or perturbed by errors), quantum encryption should work fine.

As an example of how flexible this could be, imagine a truck showing up once a month with a big box of qubits entangled with corresponding qubits at your bank. You can then use quantum teleportation as your quantum channel: you mix up the qubit you want to send with one of your entangled bits in a particular way, measure them both, then use the existing classical internet to tell the bank which entangled qubit you used and what the measurement outcome was (so they can recover your qubit on their end).

(Of course, it's a bit silly to consume bell pairs to set up your quantum crypto; they're already directly useful for that.)

*Existing* infrastructure wouldn't work for a lot of reasons. You need to be careful to not make copies of quantum information when handling it, which is expensive and difficult and generally a pain, so of course existing machinery doesn't bother and wouldn't work for this purpose at all.